# Redux - State is updating but React components are not

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Redux/ React-Redux isn't returning the state via mapStateToProps to the components despite the reducer correctly firing and assembling the correct state.  I've followed the Redux code and the state seems to flow through, but flat out is not returned to the React component despite having wrapped it in the connect function.

Code excerpt below:

index.js (My app)

```
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from './store/index';
import { fetchData, ghostFlag, dropDowned, addAttribute, setSelectedItem } from './actions/docActions';

    ...some code...

    render(){

      return(

        <span className = "app-container" id = {this.props.sidebar_shown}>

          <div className="sidebar" >

    <div className = "add_content_1"> 
                <h2 className="page-add-subheader">Content</h2>
                <TextAddContainer BlogSnapshot = {this.props.getSnapshot} CurrentEditPageHandle = {this.props.CurrentEditPageHandle} />
                <SidebarImageContainer CurrentEditPageHandle = {this.props.CurrentEditPageHandle}  />
              </div>



const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps)  => {
  console.log("The state is:"+state);
  return state;
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    fetchData: () => dispatch(fetchData (typeVar, snapshot)),

    updateHandle: () => dispatch(updateHandle(handle)),

  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store = {store}>
  <App />
  </Provider>,

    document.getElementById('root')
);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Store :

```
import React from 'react';
import {applyMiddleware, createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import {rootReducer} from '../reducers/reducers';

export const store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
        state: rootReducer
    }),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);

import undoable, { distinctState } from 'redux-undo';
```

Reducers (confirmed working in devtools, but the returned state is NOT reaching my components!):

```
export const rootReducer = ( state , action) => {

    if(typeof(state) === "undefined"){
        state = 0;
    }

    switch (action.type){
        case 'SELECTED':
            return Object.assign({}, state, {

            })

        case 'DROPDOWN':
            return Object.assign({}, state, {

            })
        case 'PAGESNAP':
            if(action.payload){
                return Object.assign({}, state, {
                    PagesSnapshot : action.payload  
                })              
            }else { return state}

        case 'BLOGSNAP':
            if(action.payload){
                return Object.assign({}, state, {
                    BlogSnapshot : action.payload   
                })              
            }else { return state}
        case 'IMAGESNAP':
            if(action.payload){
                return Object.assign({}, state, {
                    ImageSnapshot : action.payload  
                })              
            }else { return state}
        case 'CURRENTEDITPAGE':
            return Object.assign( {}, state, {
                CurrentEditPageHandle : action.payload
            })

        default:
            return state
    }


}
```

As you can see I've mapped the connect function accordingly.  What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue exists because you're referencing `<App />` in the same file you're exporting it. At the time it's being rendered, you haven't actually connected your App to your store. You need `<App />` to essentially be the connected version (`export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);`).

The easiest way to remedy this, is to move the class to `App.js` and call it like below:

App.js:

```
class App {
    render() {
       ...
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps)  => {
  console.log("The state is:"+state);
  return state;
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    fetchData: () => dispatch(fetchData (typeVar, snapshot)),

    updateHandle: () => dispatch(updateHandle(handle)),

  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

index.js:

```
import App from './app'
...Setup store...

ReactDOM.render(
 <Provider store = {store}>
    <App />
 </Provider>,

 document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Hmmm... That's great advice but doesn't seem to have fixed the issue.  I've refactored it as you mentioned and set up the store within the index.js file but the updated state still doesn't seem to be reaching the App, despite the console acknowledging the state has updated.

Just to be sure- I *should* be able to access the state as props from within the App component, right?  Hence the name "mapStateToProps"?

Comment: @camelCaseCowboy Can you create a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lOmyoxQw1) demonstrating your issue?

Comment: @camelCaseCowboy are you sure you're rendering the component returned from `connect()` and not the `<App/>` component in `ReactDOM.render()` ?

Comment: I made an example codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/w0xlllq62k.  To answer your question vhflat- I have wrapped my exported App React Component within the connect function and am now importing it to index.js, which contains the ReactDOM method per FrankerZ's instructions.  Are you referring to the "Provider" component?  Because I've made sure to wrap the app in that in the index file...

Comment: OP also had a store issue (He was creating another store entirely, and using that in his dispatch functions), so the updates weren't being translated to prop changes, as he has updating the wrong redux store.

Comment: Thanks to FrankerZ for the help- the issue ended up being some minor syntax issues between the three files that handle the reducers.